# Multiple rollbacks to diferents methods Entity Framework VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

I have this case: I'm using Entity Framework 6 and I'm trying to insert registries into multiple tables like this:

```
public function method1(model as modelType) as result

dim answer = new result(false)
dim ent = new entitiType

 Using context as database1Context

  Using dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction()
   Try
    model.property3 = method2(model.property2, model.property2)
    model.property4 = method3() 

    context.ent.add(model)
    contex.savechanges()
    answer.ok = true
    DbContextTransaction.Commit()

   catch ex as Exception

     answer.detail = ex.innerException.Message
     DbContextTransaction.Rollback()

    End Try

   End Using

  End Using

 Return Answer

End Function
```

This is my method2:

```
public function method2(idcta as integer) as integer

 dim folio As integer

 using context as new database1Context
 dim values = (From a In context.cuentas 
              Where a.idcta = idcta Select a).SingleOrDefault()

 values.property = values.property +1
 context.savechanges()

End Function
```

(The `method3` is identical to `method2`)

My question is, how can I roll back every insert or update, when any one of these methods fails?

Thank you for your help.